Tkinter - control the location of colorchooser
I have a program where I want to use the colorchooser dialog from tkinter.
My problem is that the color chooser dialog is always opening on the top left of the root window.
For example with the following code I get it as shown in the picture.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor

class App():
    def __init__(self, master):  
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('400x200')
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.master, text='Select a Color', command=self.change_color)
        self.button.pack(expand=True)
        
    def change_color(self):
        colors = askcolor(title="Tkinter Color Chooser")
        root.configure(bg=colors[1])

root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.master.mainloop()


Is there a possibility to adjust the initial location of the dialog?
For example that it is always orientated relatively to the button which opens the dialog?

It seems it must be at this position relative to parent. So a working trick with a fake hidden parent :
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor


class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry('400x200')
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.master, text='Select a Color', command=self.change_color)
        self.button.pack(expand=True)

        self.toplevel = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        self.toplevel.withdraw()

    def change_color(self):
        x, y = self.button.winfo_rootx(), self.button.winfo_rooty()
        self.toplevel.geometry(f'+{x}+{y}')
        colors = askcolor(title="Tkinter Color Chooser", parent=self.toplevel)
        root.configure(bg=colors[1])


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
app.master.mainloop()

